# subscribe to a websocket channel as an Android client

Tags: android, websocket

I'm trying to subscribe to a websocket channel as an Android client.
I need a URI websocket Server and URI of the channel to test my code.
I've already tested my code with another URI but I'm recieving only the heartbeat of the server and I couldn't recieve any data from the topic  which I've subscribed in.
this is code:

```
public final AutobahnConnection mConnection = new AutobahnConnection();

@SuppressLint("NewApi") public void run() {
    final Autobahn.EventHandler event=new Autobahn.EventHandler() {

           @Override
           public void onEvent(String topic, Object event) {

              MyEvent1 evt = (MyEvent1) event;
              System.out.println("event "+event.toString());
           }
    };


 final String wsuri = "ws://exemple.com";

   mConnection.connect(wsuri, new Autobahn.SessionHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onOpen() {


mConnection.subscribe("topic/xxx",MyEvent1.class, event);

      }


      @Override
      public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
          System.out.println("closed");
      }
   });
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You already asked this http://stackoverflow.com/q/35986629/794749

Comment: yes, and I folowed the answer of the previous question  but I've faced this problem

Comment: In the WebSocket protocol, there is no concept like "subscribe". It seems you confuse WebSocket with MQTT.

Comment: I connect to the websocket server and then I subscirbe to the topic with the http protocol

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki So why do I connect to websocket with a client id? is websocket always broadcast?